# Tag Template Override - Access to Data

Tags: joomla-3.x, template-override

on the override for com_tags > tag > default.php

I'm trying to add the [note] data

It would seem that this > $this->item->note should work. But it doesn't

Here's a short result of the

```
<?php print_r($this->item); ?>

[0] => Joomla\CMS\Object\CMSObject Object
        (
            [_errors:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [parent_id] => 102
            [level] => 2
            [lft] => 136
            [rgt] => 137
            [alias] => school-education
            [id] => 107
            [path] => subjects/school-education
            [title] => School + Education
            [note] => School Note
```

Pulling my hair out. Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `<?php echo $this->item[0]->note; ?>` may be the solution.

Comment: That will work for the first instance of the array, but if you have multiple tags, you'll want to use a `foreach` loop